# Why can't I use stitches token in css prop?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, stitches

I believe my question is simple for those who work with stitches on a daily basis.

I was following Pedro Duarte's post and saw that there is a way to create a configuration file, that is, `stitches.config.ts`.

I did this, however, when trying to use the tokens it didn't work, it was defined like this:

```
 export const { styled } = createStitches({
  theme: {
    turq: 'rgba(0, 245, 196, 1)',
  }
})
```

After creating this token I moved on to the next step which was to create a component, which looked like this:

```
import { styled } from '@stitches/react';

export const Box = styled('div');
```

Just to test the css prop.

However, when calling the component and passing the token through the css prop it did not return a text with the token color.

The question is, did I do something wrong? This is what appears in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly ! This way...

```
// customTheme.ts
export const { styled } = createStitches({
  theme: {
    turq: 'rgba(0, 245, 196, 1)',
  }
})

// Component.ts
import { styled } from 'customTheme'

export const Box = styled('div')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just saw here that the problem was that the `styled` I was importing was not the same as the one I was exporting from `createStitches`

So to solve this, when you need `styled` you should import it straight from `stitches.config.ts`